# C++ intel_driver.hpp C1083 Cannot open include file: 'atlstr.h':No such file or directory (compiling source file main.cpp) I can't build the release

Tags: c++

I would like to build this kdmapper project but unfortunately I can't because with 'altstr.h' has an issue in the attachment can you see the details: [Kdmapper compiling and building issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCgga.jpg)

Has anybody an idea how to resolve this issue?
Thanks forward!

Comment: Looks like you need to install Atl in your Visual Studio: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-and-atl?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-and-atl?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Thank you very much! It's resolved my problem. I've just installed ATL+MFC packages under my VSC and after it I completely build my project! Thank you the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the MFC package in Visual Studio. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-and-atl?view=msvc-170